# Langchain ChatBot Default Instruction

Tags: langchain

I want to Add Default instruction Like "My Name is {name} and my gender is Male " instruction to chat bot to understand my personal details to retrive answer specifically python Langchain

```
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, max_tokens=1000,
                            model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo")
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")
    chat = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm=llm,retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(search_type="similarity_score_threshold", search_kwargs={
                              'score_threshold': 0.5}),memory=memory)

    if "messages" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.messages = []

    if not st.session_state.messages:
        welcome_message = {"role": "assistant",
                            "content": "Hello, how can i help?"}
        st.session_state.messages.append(welcome_message)

    for i,message in st.session_state.messages:
        with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
            st.markdown(message["content"])


    if prompt := st.chat_input("State your question"):
        st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})
        with st.chat_message("user"):
            st.markdown(prompt)
        result = chat({"question": prompt, "chat_history": [
                    (message["role"], message["content"]) for message in st.session_state.messages]})

        with st.chat_message("assistant",avatar=darAIlogo):
            full_response = result["answer"]
            st.markdown(full_response)

        st.session_state.messages.append(
            {"role": "assistant", "content": full_response})
```

If i ask for What is my dress code .. It should understand i am a male bansed on that it should return the answer

Comment: Got the answer after workout.. We can pass the required data along with question in prompt .. it will remember the context